# ¿por que las cookies extraídas con selenium no sirven en la extensión de chrome editthiscookies?

Tags: python, cookies

utilizo `cookies = driver.get_cookies()` lo cual me da una lista de cookies en la variable cookies pero al introducirlo en editthiscookies con la misma url de donde las saque, devuelve error, veo que las cookies diferen ligeramente de las que exporta editthiscookies, existe alguna forma de corregir las cookes de get_cookies para que funcionen en editthiscookies?